Has scaffold db context changed in EF Core 8 vs. EF Core 6?
In all other versions of ASP.NET Core this command has worked:
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myLocalSQLserver;Database=ExampleDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
But with .NET8 it wont work. Does someone know any difference how to use this commad in .net8?
I use the same version number of those 2 needed packages as my .net version is.
This is important but in this case it is not the problem.

What does won't work mean? Post the actual error message. For starters, that's not an EF Core command, it's a Visual Studio Package Manager command. The EF command is dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ... The Scaffolding documentation shows how to use both the EF commands and the Visual Studio Package Manager Commands
